# How to take data from active workbook, copy it into another and then save the changed file as new file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big inventory workbook that traces all transactions of wares between warehouses and outlets (let's call it "inventory 01-01-19.xlsm"). I want to create a macro to "End the Day" by taking "final inventory" column of some sheets, opening readied template (not a template per se, just a readied xlsm file in the same folder, let's call it template.xlsm), putting the data into "starting inventory" column in the corresponding sheets of the template.xlsm and then save the template.xlsm as new file with name based on date (e.g. "inventory 01-02-19.xlsm") but **not save any changes to template.xlsm.** Obviously the first workbook is also created from same template, and all mentioned workbooks have macros enabled.

Right now I'm quite new to vba in Excel, but **have programming background** and am able to follow complex instructions and explanations, I prefer them even, but haven't tried anything before getting some good guidelines and ideas for the task at hand.

Comment: I think you could get 90% of the way to your goal by turning on the Macro Recorder and doing these steps manually. Have you considered trying that first? It is pretty helpful to get started with new VBA-powered processes, especially if you are new to programming (or new to VBA).

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, but I prefer to code my way to the solution. I made some vba in excel already, it works perfectly, and as I've said, I'm already a programmer but this goes beyond the scope of my current knowledge of VBA and I really don't have time for half solutions or to browse trough ton of sources for the exact methods and functions that actually accomplish said task. I need some guidelines at the very least, or just a kick in the right direction to get me started, but prefer some clear cut instructions on how to set it up and code it.

Comment: Your response doesn't make sense to me. The Macro Recorder *writes VBA* based on what you type/click while it's active; it seems contradictory for you to say "no thanks" to that and then say "I just need some guidelines to get me started". Your choices here are: read the docs and learn for yourself (time consuming/inefficient, but reliable and probably will teach you what you want), use the Macro Recorder (quick, reliable, and teaches you what you want), or have someone hand you a solution (quick, but unreliable, and doesn't teach you anything).

Comment: Your question says you are able to follow complex instructions and explanations, and that you even *prefer* them, yet you "don't have time to browse through sources for exact methods and functions" that "actually accomplish" said task. So... which is it?

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding, Macro recorder was explained to me differently but after further reading into it (thanks to You, dear TylerH) I think I now have the right tool to learn what I need. Thx again and have a nice day!

Comment: Best of luck with it; if you run it and still can't achieve your goal with the recorded code, feel free to edit your question to add in the VBA that you have at that point and folks ought to be able to provide assistance with it.